# What is the relation between the effect size and correlation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, effect-size, differences

Correlation refers to the degree to which a pair of variables is linearly related. The effect size quantifies some difference between two groups (e.g. the difference between the means of two datasets). For example, there's the [Cohen's effect size](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_d).

It seems to me that these concepts are related, but how exactly are they related?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, Cohen's $d$ and the correlation coefficient $r$ are conceptually related, in at least two ways:

- Both are effect sizes, because both quantify the *size* of an *effect* (yes, it's that litteral!). Cohen's $d$ quantifies the difference between the means of two populations, and $r$ quantifies how robust is the relationship between two variables.
- $r^2$ is the proportion of variance shared by the two variables. The greater  the $r^2$, the more closely the variables vary together. Cohen's $d$ is not a proportion of variance strictly speaking but it's conceptually related. Take a group of teenagers, all of the same sex. You could probably not tell 15 from 16-year-olds based on their height alone: most of the variability across the two sub-populations is not due to age because the effect size $d$ is very small (around 0.2). However, if you mix preteens and young adults, a substantial amount of variability in heigts can be ascribed to differences in age, and the effect size is indeed much larger (around 1).

However, it is important to remember that $r$ and $d$ are very different and bear no direct relationship. They quantify entirely different types of phenomena. Two series of values can have exactly the same mean ($d=0$) and be totally uncorrelated ($r=0$) or highly correlated ($r=1$); every combination is possible.

Comment: Re "it is important to remember that r and d are very different and bear no direct relationship:" quite to the contrary, they enjoy a perfect mathematical relation, as Cohen explains.  See *Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences* (2nd Ed.) at section 2.2.2, "$d$ in terms of correlation and proportion of variance."

Comment: @whuber Indeed, there are two formulas given in your reference, depending on whether the two groups being compared are approximately equal in size or not. One is simply a special case of the other, however.