# What does reported "r" mean in the context of a t-test?

Tags: correlation, t-test, effect-size

In a psychological paper (Fujita et al., 2006), the authors perform a two sample t-test for independent means. They report the following values:

$M_1$ = 9.88, $M_2$ = 8.47,

*t(66)* = 2.25, *p* = 0.03, $p_{rep}$ = .94, *r* = .27

What does *r* mean in this context? Is it a correlation coefficient or is it an effect size? In the back of my head, I remember that *r* can be an effect size. I wish to know the effect size. [What is the relation between the effect size and correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412590/what-is-the-relation-between-the-effect-size-and-correlation) gives me some understanding, but how exactly can I interpret this *r* or convert it do Cohen's  *d*?

For those who wonder what $p_{rep}$ is: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-rep) says it is a bad measure, nowadays its conception is proven to contain mathematical errors.

---

(The paper is behind a paywall)

###### Fujita, K., Henderson, M. D., Eng, J., Trope, Y., & Liberman, N. (2006). Spatial Distance and Mental Construal of Social Events. Psychological Science, 17(4), 278-282. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9280.2006.01698.x

Comment: Please provide a full citation for (Fujita et al., 2006). Then -- if the paper is not behind a paywall -- the answers won't have to make guesses about the "usual" and "without further information".

Comment: @dipetkov I looked it up and the paper is behind a paywall, sorry. But actually the paper is not important though, because I included everything that is relevant in my question. It could be about any paper that reports $r$ along with a t-test. You have to take my word that there is nothing else that is useful in this paper to answer this question. $r$ is just dropped after a $t$ statistic and $p$ value, no explanations.

Comment: I disagree. This is not about "taking your word for it" but about the citation itself. If the paper was irrelevant why mention (Fujita et al., 2006) but not the full citation? I know that CV has no rule about citations; however, I think they are important when you are referring to someone else's work, hence my comment.

Comment: Also, now you have one answer that is upvoted but (probably) wrong because, in a two sample situation we won't even compute a correlation unless the samples are paired. Perhaps this is what @PeterFlom referred to.

Comment: i added the reference. And what you are saying, we won't even compute the correlation, is interesting. Why not? The important thing, that it is a two independent samples scenario was clearly stated in my question though.

Comment: Thank you. Correlation is computed between two measurements taken from the same sample / person / object. Say we have two groups, men and women; we can't "align" those to compute a sample correlation coefficient; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Sample_correlation_coefficient). Unless perhaps we have a sample of partnered couples; then we can pair those.

Comment: It's true, your question is clear & the thing about proper citing of sources is something of a pet peeve of mine. What I noticed is that the two answers are incompatible but I admit that's not due to the content of your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reported $r$ is usually referring to an effect size. It is calculated from the t-statistic and the degrees of freedom

$$
r = \sqrt{\frac{t^2}{t^2 + df}}
$$

where $t$ is the t-statistic and $df$ is the degrees of freedom ($N-2$)
​

​

Comment: is this $r$ equivalent to calculating a certain correlation directly from the data? I wonder: is it possible to transform this formula to the formula of some correlation coefficient?

Comment: As already commented, a correlation is only defined if the data are paired.

Comment: Interesting, does this effect size have a name? Since usually effect sizes aim to provide a standardized measure of effect which is independent of sample size (in contrast to quantities such as the p-value), it seems a bit odd that $df$ is included in the formula.

Comment: @LuckyPal I think it is about removing the influence of sample size ($df$) from the test statistic ($t$ in this case), that's why it is in the denominator.

Answer (score 8):

Without any other information, I would say $r$ is correlation. And that is an effect size.